# Firebase Android onDataChange will not call

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I'm trying to do is get a list of user IDs from Firebase, then get the data from each of those users. The issue I'm having is that while I can quite happily retrieve the list of IDs, it doesn't seem to work - the `onDataChange` for this query is never reached.

I have tried amending the code within `configurePage` by removing the for loop and even hardcoding a value for ID, but no matter what I do nothing is ever added to `listOfItems` and you still cannot reach `onDataChange`. The log line in `configurePage` shows the correct number of IDs, so I can rule out the first query not finishing in time for the second to start.

First query:

```
public void getIDs() {
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    search = mDatabase.child("linked_users").child(userID);
    val = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Test:" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            for (DataSnapshot singleChild : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                listOfIDs.add(singleChild.getKey());
            }
            if (listOfIDs.size() == 0) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                noResultsLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                countLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                countLabel.setText("Total users: " + listOfIDs.size());
                countLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                configurePage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DB problem");
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AgentViewUsers.this);
            dialog = databaseDialog(dialog);
            dialog.show();
        }
    };
    search.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(val);
}
```

Second query:

```
public void configurePage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "test = " + listOfIDs.size());
    for (String id : listOfIDs){
        mDatabase.child("users").child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                AgentUserViewObject obj = new AgentUserViewObject();
                obj.name = dataSnapshot.child("full_name").getValue().toString();
                obj.address = dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue().toString() + ", " + dataSnapshot.child("towncounty").getValue().toString() + ", " + dataSnapshot.child("postcode").getValue().toString();
                obj.requestCount = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("requests_submitted").getValue().toString());
                listOfItems.add(obj);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(AgentViewUsers.this);
    mAdapter = new AgentUserViewAdapter(listOfItems);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(AgentViewUsers.this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Add a `Log` statement to `onCancelled()` of the second query to see if security rules are causing the read to fail.

Comment: Added a Log - neither onCancelled or onDataChange call.

Comment: I stand corrected. Further investigation shows that it is now calling the onDataChange and retrieving data, but that this is not being retrieved in time for the end of the for loop, therefore it's still empty when the recycler view is set.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is expected behavior. Firebase (like most modern cloud APIs) loads and updates the data from the server asynchronously. So when you call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` it *starts* synchronizing the data. But it won't be done with that until (potentially much) later.

For that reason you should think differently when dealing with Firebase. Instead of coding "first get the data, then update the list view with that data", reframe the code as "whenever we get data, we update the list view with that data".

In this reframed approach, you'll want to update the list view from within the `onDataChange()` method. To do that, you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
Log.d(TAG, "test = " + listOfIDs.size());
for (String id : listOfIDs){
    mDatabase.child("users").child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            AgentUserViewObject obj = new AgentUserViewObject();
            obj.name = dataSnapshot.child("full_name").getValue().toString();
            obj.address = dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue().toString() + ", " + dataSnapshot.child("towncounty").getValue().toString() + ", " + dataSnapshot.child("postcode").getValue().toString();
            obj.requestCount = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("requests_submitted").getValue().toString());
            listOfItems.add(obj);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // tell the adapter to redraw the view
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(AgentViewUsers.this);
mAdapter = new AgentUserViewAdapter(listOfItems);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(AgentViewUsers.this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```